# Empathy disappears every time i open it

Tags: 11.10, empathy

I'm using ubuntu 11.10, gnome shell 3.2.1 and when ever i open empathy, empathy contact    list disappears.
 when i try to open it via terminal,it still opens and disappears

*** glibc detected**  empathy: corrupted double-linked list: 0x087f2a88 **

======= Backtrace: =========

/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6ebc2)[0x7550bc2]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6fa28)[0x7551a28]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0x755494d]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x49c1b)[0x2507c1b]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_free+0x36)[0x2507ef6]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0(+0x1ca6b)[0x315a6b]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0(+0x1cb76)[0x315b76]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_object_unref+0x19a)[0x47c68a]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(+0xa2d6b)[0x464cd6b]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_cell_renderer_get_preferred_width+0x140)[0x4644630]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_cell_area_request_renderer+0x200)[0x463b190]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x91de5)[0x463bde5]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x93c26)[0x463dc26]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_cell_area_get_preferred_width+0xd2)[0x4637892]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_tree_view_column_cell_get_size+0xd5)[0x4844975]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x27fa92)[0x4829a92]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x28077b)[0x482a77b]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x280bba)[0x482abba]
/usr/lib/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x127fe)[0x2647fe]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x3f110)[0x24fd110]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x1df)[0x250125f]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x43990)[0x2501990]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_loop_run+0x14b)[0x2501f9b]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_main+0xa5)[0x4701f95]
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x6bfe4)[0x4615fe4]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0(g_application_run+0x19c)[0x7f0150c]
empathy(main+0xa1)[0x8078171]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x74fb113]
empathy[0x80781b1]

======= Memory map: ========

00110000-00132000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 394831     /usr/lib/libfolks-telepathy.so.25.2.2
00132000-00133000 r--p 00021000 07:00 394831     /usr/lib/libfolks-telepathy.so.25.2.2
00133000-00134000 rw-p 00022000 07:00 394831     /usr/lib/libfolks-telepathy.so.25.2.2
00134000-00215000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 394968     /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0.29.0
00215000-00218000 r--p 000e0000 07:00 394968     /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0.29.0
00218000-00219000 rw-p 000e3000 07:00 394968     /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0.29.0
00219000-0021a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0021a000-0024a000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 395313     /usr/lib/libtelepathy-logger.so.2.2.0
0024a000-0024b000 r--p 0002f000 07:00 395313     /usr/lib/libtelepathy-logger.so.2.2.0
0024b000-0024c000 rw-p 00030000 07:00 395313     /usr/lib/libtelepathy-logger.so.2.2.0
0024c000-00250000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 391996     /usr/lib/libcanberra-gtk3.so.0.1.8
00250000-00251000 r--p 00003000 07:00 391996     /usr/lib/libcanberra-gtk3.so.0.1.8
00251000-00252000 rw-p 00004000 07:00 391996     /usr/lib/libcanberra-gtk3.so.0.1.8
00252000-002c8000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 394799     /usr/lib/libgdk-3.so.0.200.0
002c8000-002ca000 r--p 00075000 07:00 394799     /usr/lib/libgdk-3.so.0.200.0
002ca000-002cb000 rw-p 00077000 07:00 394799     /usr/lib/libgdk-3.so.0.200.0
002cb000-002cf000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397245     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0.3000.0
002cf000-002d0000 r--p 00003000 07:00 397245     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0.3000.0
002d0000-002d1000 rw-p 00004000 07:00 397245     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0.3000.0
002d1000-002d4000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397231     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.3000.0
002d4000-002d5000 r--p 00002000 07:00 397231     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.3000.0
002d5000-002d6000 rw-p 00003000 07:00 397231     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.3000.0
002d8000-002d9000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
002d9000-002f7000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397223     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.2400.0
002f7000-002f8000 r--p 0001d000 07:00 397223     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.2400.0
002f8000-002f9000 rw-p 0001e000 07:00 397223     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.2400.0
002f9000-00340000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397311     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0.2903.0
00340000-00341000 r--p 00047000 07:00 397311     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0.2903.0
00341000-00342000 rw-p 00048000 07:00 397311     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0.2903.0
00342000-00359000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 784530     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
00359000-0035a000 r--p 00016000 07:00 784530     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
0035a000-0035b000 rw-p 00017000 07:00 784530     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
0035b000-0035d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0035d000-00389000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 392125     /usr/lib/libgconf-2.so.4.1.5
00389000-0038a000 r--p 0002b000 07:00 392125     /usr/lib/libgconf-2.so.4.1.5
0038a000-0038b000 rw-p 0002c000 07:00 392125     /usr/lib/libgconf-2.so.4.1.5
0038d000-003bd000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 394851     /usr/lib/libnm-glib.so.4.2.0
003bd000-003be000 r--p 00030000 07:00 394851     /usr/lib/libnm-glib.so.4.2.0
003be000-003bf000 rw-p 00031000 07:00 394851     /usr/lib/libnm-glib.so.4.2.0
003bf000-00419000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 395172     /usr/lib/libunity.so.6.2.0
00419000-0041b000 r--p 00059000 07:00 395172     /usr/lib/libunity.so.6.2.0
0041b000-0041c000 rw-p 0005b000 07:00 395172     /usr/lib/libunity.so.6.2.0
0041c000-0046a000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 394871     /usr/lib/libgee.so.2.0.0
0046a000-0046c000 r--p 0004d000 07:00 394871     /usr/lib/libgee.so.2.0.0
0046c000-0046d000 rw-p 0004f000 07:00 394871     /usr/lib/libgee.so.2.0.0
0046d000-004ba000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397239     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3000.0
004ba000-004bb000 r--p 0004d000 07:00 397239     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3000.0
004bb000-004bc000 rw-p 0004e000 07:00 397239     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3000.0
004bc000-004cc000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 784543     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.12.0
004cc000-004cd000 r--p 0000f000 07:00 784543     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.12.0
004cd000-004ce000 rw-p 00010000 07:00 784543     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.12.0
004ce000-004d5000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 784534     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
004d5000-004d6000 r--p 00006000 07:00 784534     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
004d6000-004d7000 rw-p 00007000 07:00 784534     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
004d7000-004da000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 784481     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
004da000-004db000 r--p 00002000 07:00 784481     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
004db000-004dc000 rw-p 00003000 07:00 784481     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
004dc000-004dd000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397720     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-svg.so
004dd000-004de000 r--p 00000000 07:00 397720     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-svg.so
004de000-004df000 rw-p 00001000 07:00 397720     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-svg.so
004df000-00521000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 394722     /usr/lib/libebook-1.2.so.12.3.1
00521000-00524000 r--p 00042000 07:00 394722     /usr/lib/libebook-1.2.so.12.3.1
00524000-00525000 rw-p 00045000 07:00 394722     /usr/lib/libebook-1.2.so.12.3.1
00525000-00590000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 396166     /usr/lib/libcamel-1.2.so.29.0.0
00590000-00593000 r--p 0006a000 07:00 396166     /usr/lib/libcamel-1.2.so.29.0.0
00593000-005a7000 rw-p 0006d000 07:00 396166     /usr/lib/libcamel-1.2.so.29.0.0
005a7000-005ea000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 392078     /usr/lib/libedataserver-1.2.so.15.0.0
005ea000-005eb000 ---p 00043000 07:00 392078     /usr/lib/libedataserver-1.2.so.15.0.0
005eb000-005ec000 r--p 00043000 07:00 392078     /usr/lib/libedataserver-1.2.so.15.0.0
005ec000-005ed000 rw-p 00044000 07:00 392078     /usr/lib/libedataserver-1.2.so.15.0.0
005ed000-005ef000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397127     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
005ef000-005f0000 r--p 00001000 07:00 397127     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
005f0000-005f1000 rw-p 00002000 07:00 397127     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
005f1000-0060f000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 784457     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
0060f000-00610000 r--p 0001d000 07:00 784457     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
00610000-00611000 rw-p 0001e000 07:00 784457     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
00611000-007bf000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 395311     /usr/lib/libtelepathy-glib.so.0.61.0
007bf000-007c0000 ---p 001ae000 07:00 395311     /usr/lib/libtelepathy-glib.so.0.61.0
007c0000-007c3000 r--p 001ae000 07:00 395311     /usr/lib/libtelepathy-glib.so.0.61.0
007c3000-007c7000 rw-p 001b1000 07:00 395311     /usr/lib/libtelepathy-glib.so.0.61.0
007c7000-007c8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
007c8000-0080f000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 784480     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.5.7
0080f000-00810000 r--p 00046000 07:00 784480     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.5.7
00810000-00811000 rw-p 00047000 07:00 784480     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.5.7
00812000-0081c000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 394811     /usr/lib/libenchant.so.1.6.0
0081c000-0081d000 r--p 00009000 07:00 394811     /usr/lib/libenchant.so.1.6.0
0081d000-0081e000 rw-p 0000a000 07:00 394811     /usr/lib/libenchant.so.1.6.0
0081e000-00965000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 395414     /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.8
00965000-00969000 r--p 00147000 07:00 395414     /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.8
00969000-0096a000 rw-p 0014b000 07:00 395414     /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.8
0096a000-0096b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0096b000-00a9c000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397107     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
00a9c000-00a9d000 ---p 00131000 07:00 397107     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
00a9d000-00a9e000 r--p 00131000 07:00 397107     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
00a9e000-00aa0000 rw-p 00132000 07:00 397107     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
00aa0000-00aa1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00aa1000-00ab4000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 784553     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
00ab4000-00ab5000 r--p 00012000 07:00 784553     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
00ab5000-00ab6000 rw-p 00013000 07:00 784553     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
00ab6000-00ad3000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397405     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
00ad3000-00ad4000 r--p 0001c000 07:00 397405     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
00ad4000-00ad5000 rw-p 0001d000 07:00 397405     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
00ad5000-00add000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397395     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbisfile.so.3.3.4
00add000-00ade000 r--p 00007000 07:00 397395     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbisfile.so.3.3.4
00ade000-00adf000 rw-p 00008000 07:00 397395     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbisfile.so.3.3.4
00adf000-00ae7000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 395104     /usr/lib/libltdl.so.7.3.0
00ae7000-00ae8000 r--p 00008000 07:00 395104     /usr/lib/libltdl.so.7.3.0
00ae8000-00ae9000 rw-p 00009000 07:00 395104     /usr/lib/libltdl.so.7.3.0
00ae9000-00aed000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397121     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
00aed000-00aee000 r--p 00003000 07:00 397121     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
00aee000-00aef000 rw-p 00004000 07:00 397121     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
00af0000-00b42000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 394833     /usr/lib/libfolks.so.25.2.2
00b42000-00b44000 r--p 00051000 07:00 394833     /usr/lib/libfolks.so.25.2.2
00b44000-00b45000 rw-p 00053000 07:00 394833     /usr/lib/libfolks.so.25.2.2
00b45000-00b94000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 394725     /usr/lib/libnm-util.so.2.1.0
00b94000-00b95000 ---p 0004f000 07:00 394725     /usr/lib/libnm-util.so.2.1.0
00b95000-00b96000 r--p 0004f000 07:00 394725     /usr/lib/libnm-util.so.2.1.0
00b96000-00b97000 rw-p 00050000 07:00 394725     /usr/lib/libnm-util.so.2.1.0
00b97000-00b98000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397824     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-thai-lang.so
00b98000-00b99000 r--p 00000000 07:00 397824     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-thai-lang.so
00b99000-00b9a000 rw-p 00001000 07:00 397824     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-thai-lang.so
00b9a000-00ba0000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397292     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.4.0.0
00ba0000-00ba1000 r--p 00005000 07:00 397292     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.4.0.0
00ba1000-00ba2000 rw-p 00006000 07:00 397292     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.4.0.0
00ba2000-00bb3000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397378     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtdb.so.1.2.9
00bb3000-00bb4000 r--p 00010000 07:00 397378     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtdb.so.1.2.9
00bb4000-00bb5000 rw-p 00011000 07:00 397378     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtdb.so.1.2.9
00bb5000-00bbc000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 392133     /usr/lib/libgailutil-3.so.0.0.0
00bbc000-00bbd000 r--p 00007000 07:00 392133     /usr/lib/libgailutil-3.so.0.0.0
00bbd000-00bbe000 rw-p 00008000 07:00 392133     /usr/lib/libgailutil-3.so.0.0.0
00bbe000-00bc9000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 394938     /usr/lib/libgstapp-0.10.so.0.24.0
00bc9000-00bca000 r--p 0000a000 07:00 394938     /usr/lib/libgstapp-0.10.so.0.24.0
00bca000-00bcb000 rw-p 0000b000 07:00 394938     /usr/lib/libgstapp-0.10.so.0.24.0
00bcb000-00be9000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 394964     /usr/lib/libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0.24.0
00be9000-00bea000 r--p 0001e000 07:00 394964     /usr/lib/libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0.24.0
00bea000-00beb000 rw-p 0001f000 07:00 394964     /usr/lib/libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0.24.0
00beb000-00bf6000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 394980     /usr/lib/libgstvideo-0.10.so.0.24.0
00bf6000-00bf7000 r--p 0000a000 07:00 394980     /usr/lib/libgstvideo-0.10.so.0.24.0
00bf7000-00bf8000 rw-p 0000b000 07:00 394980     /usr/lib/libgstvideo-0.10.so.0.24.0
00bf8000-00bfd000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397169     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2.11000.2
00bfd000-00bfe000 r--p 00005000 07:00 397169     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2.11000.2
00bfe000-00bff000 rw-p 00006000 07:00 397169     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2.11000.2
00c00000-00c20000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 394900     /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.1.1
00c20000-00c21000 r--p 0001f000 07:00 394900     /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.1.1
00c21000-00c22000 rw-p 00020000 07:00 394900     /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.1.1
00c22000-00c24000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397111     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1.0.0
00c24000-00c25000 r--p 00001000 07:00 397111     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1.0.0
00c25000-00c26000 rw-p 00002000 07:00 397111     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1.0.0
00c28000-00c4b000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397192     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-glib-1.so.2.2.0
00c4b000-00c4c000 r--p 00022000 07:00 397192     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-glib-1.so.2.2.0
00c4c000-00c4d000 rw-p 00023000 07:00 397192     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-glib-1.so.2.2.0
00c4d000-00ccf000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 784493     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
00ccf000-00cd0000 r--p 00081000 07:00 784493     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
00cd0000-00cd2000 rw-p 00082000 07:00 784493     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
00cd2000-00cef000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397145     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0.20209.1
00cef000-00cf1000 r--p 0001c000 07:00 397145     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0.20209.1
00cf1000-00cf2000 rw-p 0001e000 07:00 397145     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0.20209.1
00cf2000-00cfd000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397313     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.2903.0
00cfd000-00cfe000 r--p 0000a000 07:00 397313     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.2903.0
00cfe000-00cff000 rw-p 0000b000 07:00 397313     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.2903.0
00cff000-00d08000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397131     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
00d08000-00d09000 r--p 00008000 07:00 397131     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
00d09000-00d0a000 rw-p 00009000 07:00 397131     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
00d0a000-00d0c000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397115     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
00d0c000-00d0d000 r--p 00001000 07:00 397115     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
00d0d000-00d0e000 rw-p 00002000 07:00 397115     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
00d0e000-00d10000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397403     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0.0.0
00d10000-00d11000 r--p 00001000 07:00 397403     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0.0.0
00d11000-00d12000 rw-p 00002000 07:00 397403     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0.0.0
00d12000-00d21000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 394958     /usr/lib/libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0.24.0
00d21000-00d22000 ---p 0000f000 07:00 394958     /usr/lib/libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0.24.0
00d22000-00d23000 r--p 0000f000 07:00 394958     /usr/lib/libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0.24.0
00d23000-00d24000 rw-p 00010000 07:00 394958     /usr/lib/libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0.24.0
00d24000-00d35000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397119     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
00d35000-00d36000 r--p 00010000 07:00 397119     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
00d36000-00d37000 rw-p 00011000 07:00 397119     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
00d37000-00d3a000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 784497     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
00d3a000-00d3b000 r--p 00002000 07:00 784497     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
00d3b000-00d3c000 rw-p 00003000 07:00 784497     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
00d3c000-00d4b000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 395060     /usr/lib/libido3-0.1.so.0.0.0
00d4b000-00d4c000 r--p 0000e000 07:00 395060     /usr/lib/libido3-0.1.so.0.0.0
00d4c000-00d4d000 rw-p 0000f000 07:00 395060     /usr/lib/libido3-0.1.so.0.0.0
00d4d000-00d6f000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397262     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
00d6f000-00d70000 r--p 00022000 07:00 397262     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
00d70000-00d71000 rw-p 00023000 07:00 397262     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
00d71000-00d78000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 397129     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
00d78000-00d79000 r--p 00006000 07:00 397129     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2.2.0Aborted

Answer (score 1):

I've found similar issues with both pidgin and Empathy when using the skype plugin (or other third-party plugins).  Once, things seemed to go corrupt for no reason at all.  I fixed it the same way in all cases: Deleting the configuration and re-adding my accounts.

For Empathy on Oneiric, the files are in the following locations:

- `~/.mission-control/` directory (accounts configuration is stored here)
- `~/.gconf/apps/empathy/` directory (this is where gconf-editor stores the empathy config)
- `~/.config/Empathy/` directory (contact groups are stored here)
- `/org/gnome/empathy/` dconf tree (app preferences are stored here)

You can reset the dconf tree to system defaults with the following command:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/empathy/
```

Resetting the dconf tree and deleting (or renaming) those directories will almost certainly allow Empathy to work correctly once again.  Once you have a functional app, you can add accounts one at a time, and see where the trouble lies.